# Why is a feedback loop "appropriate" design for instruments that don't physically contain such loop?

Tags: audio, signal-synthesis

Why is a feedback loop "appropriate" design for instruments that don't physically contain such loop? Or do they?

See e.g. paragraph 7.7, and Figure 7.9 (shown here):

[image]

[https://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~clark/nordmodularbook/nm_physical.html](https://www.cim.mcgill.ca/%7Eclark/nordmodularbook/nm_physical.html)

It's intuitive that it may produce suitable tones, but does this make sense in the physical setting? A clarinet as a feedback loop?

Comment: Out of that entire book chapter that you have linked to, could you pick _one specific example_, then at the very least refer to a section and perhaps a figure, or very much better quote a paragraph or give a short paraphrase or summary of what they're doing?  You're asking us to read the whole chapter then guess at which parts concern you.

Comment: Yes makes perfect sense to me. Most importantly it is a model that can sufficiently predict a result, that usually is reason enough.

Answer (score 2):

The part of your question I can't answer is the "that don't physically contain such loop" part -- because they all do.

Yes, a clarinet as a feedback loop.  Pretty much all the winds can be thought of as an oscillating element whose oscillations are conditioned by the behavior of the column of air that they work into.  For that matter, any bowed instrument can be thought of as an oscillating element whose oscillations are conditioned by the string (or saw blade) that they work against.

So any reed instrument has a reed which responds to a stream of air by opening and shutting an orifice.  I can't tell you the exact physics, but the fact that it oscillates at all means that it's exhibiting some sort of negative impedance.  I.e., there's some operating range where more backpressure causes more flow.

(Brass and flutes or whistles, ditto, it's just that the mechanism of the oscillation is different.  And flames, which also exhibit negative impedance and will oscillate under the right circumstance.
And bowed string instruments also have a negative mechanical impedance element at the bow-string intersection, but the resonating element is completely different.)

Pressure pulses from the reed closing and opening travel down the body of the instrument, and reflect either off of the end of the bell (if all of the stops are closed), or off an open stop, or with several partial reflections off of several open stops.  The body of the instrument forms a resonant cavity, with the resonance adjusted by the note you're fingering.  The reed, plus your breathing, plus your embouchure, form an acoustic element with negative acoustic impedance.  The result is an oscillator.

The delay line models the resonant cavity -- it's the delay from the face of the reed to the open key and back to the reed (with all sorts of complications stemming from those partial reflections, and even more when you kick open the overtone key and have the notes -- nominally -- go up in frequency by a twelfth simply because a teeny but well-placed hole was opened up just a few inches from the reed).